# How to delete/remove polyline from Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

> I'm trying to remove/delete the line.
>   But flightPath.setMap(null) is not working.
>   I'm sending the JSFiddle link which will give you complete details. of my code.
>   [jsfiddle.net/rb9w8o5c/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/Rupesh_Singh/rb9w8o5c/5/)

```
function initialize() {
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
 }
function addLatLng(event) {
        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(event.latLng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            title: '#' + path.getLength(),
            map: map
        })
        markers.push(marker);
        for (var key in markers) {
            flightPlanCoordinates.push(markers[key].position);
            positions.push(markers[key].position);
        }
        flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });    
    }
    function removePolyline(){
         flightPath.setMap(null);
    }
```

Comment: do you want to keep the markers, or can you get rid of everything?

Comment: No !! Actually I want to delete line as well as markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removePolyline(){
        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.pop();
        marker = markers.pop();
        marker.setMap(null);
        for (var key in markers) {
            flightPlanCoordinates.push(markers[key].position);
            positions.push(markers[key].position);
        }
        flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });

}
```

Comment: Its not removing all the markers

Comment: refresh this page and try again.  i added two lines in an edit